# Microsoft express edition 2008 not saving data

Tags: vb.net

I am making a project using (Microsoft visual basic 2008 express edition), and the type of connection I used is (Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)). My code doesn't show any errors but when I enter some data and press the save button it doesn't save the data nor show any errors.

```
If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()
Conn.Open()

q1Var = "insert into usertab1("

q2Var = " values("

q1Var = q1Var & "username" & ","

q2Var = q2Var & "'" & usertxt1.Text & "',"

q1Var = q1Var & "useremail" & ","

q2Var = q2Var & "'" & usertxt2.Text & "',"

q1Var = q1Var & "userphone" & ","

q2Var = q2Var & "'" & usertxt3.Text & "',"

q1Var = q1Var & "userpwd" & ","

q2Var = q2Var & "'" & usertxt4.Text & "',"

q1Var = q1Var & "usercity" & ")"

q2Var = q2Var & "'" & usertxt5.Text & "')"

MsgBox(q1Var & q2Var)

Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(q1Var & q2Var, Conn)

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Needs a [mcve].  Are you sure your database connection parameters are correct?  You didn't show them...or the table schema.  Also, for the love of all things good, use parameters in your queries.

Comment: In addition to the SQL injection risk, use the `Using` statement to declare and use the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects. Also, you probably should include whole functions instead of snippets.

Comment: Every time you think you are changing a String, you are actually throwing it away and creating an entirely new string. Not too good for efficient code. Also, your long list of concatenation is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep you database objects local there is not need to check their state.

Do not open the connection until immediately before you use it.

`Using...End Using blocks will ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Always use parameters with the .Add method to avoid Sql injection. I have guessed at the datatypes and field sizes. You will have to check your database for the actual values.

Finally, passwords should NEVER be stored as plain text. I will leave it to you and your instructor to investigate salting and hashing.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into usertab1(username,useremail,userphone,userpwd,usercity)values(@Name, @Email, @Phone, @Password, @City);", cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = usertxt1.Text
                .Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = usertxt2.Text
                .Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = usertxt3.Text
                .Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = usertxt4.Text
                .Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = usertxt5.Text
            End With
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```